# Using ASP.NET Identity when ASP.NET Core Web API and MVC projects are separate. Which should handle the auth?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

If I were to create two separate projects:

1. ASP.NET Core Web API project
2. ASP.NET Core MVC project

The MVC project would use HttpClient to talk to the Web API.

If this is the case and I wanted to use the built in ASP.NET Identity should I be doing it through the Web API or just keep it as part of the MVC project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the description of your question, it seems like you will end up protecting only 1 layer of your app.

Ideally, you would protect both. On the MVC application side you would want to do `user authentication` with ASPNET Identity (establish who wants to get information) and on the WebAPI side you would want to do `resource authentication` or `client authentication` to check if the caller of the API (app x) actually has the rights to call the API. The latter cannot be done through ASPNET identity. You would want something like Identity Server 4 or Azure B2C like products to achieve that.

Now, you could keep the API open & internal and just call it from HTTPClient in the MVC APP, but, I wouldn't do that if I were you. The only reason I can think of why you would want an API is, so that you can later use it from other apps, so, keeping the API open like that is not advisable.

If I were in your shoes, I would want to have a security framework around my applications and then proceed with giving applications the required access on the API to carry out needed operations.

Comment: so your suggesting that I add identity server 4 (which I have used before) to the API or as its own project. Using it for auth between client apps and the API? As far as the MVC application is concerned you are saying that this is where I would use the built in identity, correct? Even for registering and logging in users though? What if a client who calls the API in the future needs to be able to register and login users? Maybe this is where identity server comes into play. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The token server should be its own project. IdSrv4, specifically, does both OAuth and OpenId Connect so you could move both user & client registration and authentication to this project. Just easier to manage everything this way in my opinion. MVC and WebAPI become consumers of this authentication service thereafter.

Comment: @MuqueetKhan You are saying to move client registration and authentication to the IdentityServer4 project. I know how to do this giving the MVC app access to the API. However, the confusion comes in when trying to authenticate and authorize users. I imagine the MVC project will flick over to the IdentityServer4 project for the user to login. If this is the case, in the MVC project, will I still be able to use the built-in ASP.NET Identity Template and Managers to say who has access to what actions? Or will this all be part of IdentityServer4 too?

Comment: Going through the same dilemma today! Any suggestions for today?

Comment: It is possible to use ASP.Net Identity in both IdProvider and MVC projects if they share the same database. But what if we decide to switch to an external or corporate IdProvider which has its own user directory?